# Burninate the [video-games] tag

Tags: discussion, tags, meta, burninate-request

### The desolation of Tags.

No, but really, what is [video-games](/questions/tagged/video-games) doing on meta anyway?

> [image]

Comment: Thank you random SO (q-banned?) citizen for exposing this tag! :D

Comment: Cool image, but there's only 3 questions with that tag. Wouldn't it have been faster to just edit them out?

Comment: +1 reading meta makes my day... my sad pitiful day

Comment: @Juhana It was to post the image.

Comment: Anna and BoltClock really do make a great tag-burninating duo...

Answer (score 1):

## Complete.